# Optimising code for matching two strings modulo scrambling

Tags: ruby

I am trying to write a function `scramble(str1, str2)` that returns `true` if a portion of `str1` characters can be rearranged to match `str2`, otherwise returns `false`. Only lower case letters (a-z) will be used. No punctuation or digits will be included. For example:

- `str1 = 'rkqodlw'; str2 = 'world'` should return `true`.
- `str1 = 'cedewaraaossoqqyt'; str2 = 'codewars'` should return `true`.
- `str1 = 'katas'; str2 = 'steak'` should return `false`.

This is my code:

```
def scramble(s1, s2)
  #sorts strings into arrays
  first = s1.split("").sort
  second = s2.split("").sort
  correctLetters = 0
  for i in 0...first.length
    #check for occurrences of first letter
    occurrencesFirst = first.count(s1[i])
    for j in 0...second.length
      #scan through second string
      occurrencesSecond = second.count(s2[j])
      #if letter to be tested is correct and occurrences of first less than occurrences of second
      #meaning word cannot be formed
      if (s2[j] == s1[i]) && occurrencesFirst < occurrencesSecond
        return false
      elsif s2[j] == s1[i]
        correctLetters += 1
      elsif first.count(s1[s2[j]]) == 0
        return false
      end
    end
  end
  if correctLetters == 0
    return false
  end
  return true
end
```

I need help optimising this code. Please give me suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one efficient and Ruby-like way of doing that.

**Code**

```
def scramble(str1, str2)
  h1 = char_counts(str1)
  h2 = char_counts(str2)
  h2.all? { |ch, nbr| nbr <= h1[ch] }
end

def char_counts(str)
  str.each_char.with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |ch, h| h[ch] += 1 }
end
```

**Examples**

```
scramble('abecacdeba', 'abceae')
  #=> true
scramble('abecacdeba', 'abweae')
  #=> false
```

**Explanation**

The three steps are as follows.

```
str1 = 'abecacdeba'
str2 = 'abceae'

h1 = char_counts(str1)
  #=> {"a"=>3, "b"=>2, "e"=>2, "c"=>2, "d"=>1}
h2 = char_counts(str2)
  #=> {"a"=>2, "b"=>1, "c"=>1, "e"=>2}
h2.all? { |ch, nbr| nbr <= h1[ch] }
  #=> true
```

The last statement is equivalent to

```
2 <= 3 && 1 <= 2 && 1 <= 2 && 2 <=2
```

The method `char_counts` constructs what is sometimes called a "counting hash".  To understand how `char_counts` works, see [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-c-new), especially the explanation of the effect of providing a default value as an argument of new. In brief, if a hash is defined `h = Hash.new(0)`, then if `h` does not have a key `k`, `h[k]` returns the default value, here `0` (and the hash is not changed).

Suppose, for different data,

```
h1 = { "a"=>2 }
h2 = { "a"=>1, "b"=>2 }
```

Then we would find that `1 <= 2 #=> true` but `2 <= 0 #=> false`, so the method would return `false`. The second comparison is `2 <= h1["b"]`. As `h1` does not have a key `"b"`, `h1["b"]` returns the default value, `0`.

The method `char_counts` is effectively a short way of writing the method expressed as follows.

```
def char_counts(str)
  h = {}
  str.each_char do |ch|
    h[ch] = 0 unless h.key?(ch) # instead of Hash.new(0)
    h[ch] = h[c] + 1            # instead of h[c][ += 1
  end
  h                             # no need for this if use `each_with_object`
end
```

See [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object), [String#each_char](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-each_char) (preferable to [String.chars](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-each_char), as the latter produces an unneeded temporary array whereas the former returns an enumerator) and [Hash#key?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-key) (or `Hash#has_key?`, `Hash#include?` or `Hash#member?`).

**An Alternative**

```
def scramble(str1, str2)
  str2.chars.difference(str1.chars).empty?
end

class Array
  def difference(other)
    h = other.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |e,h| h[e] += 1 }
    reject { |e| h[e] > 0 && h[e] -= 1 }
  end
end
```

I have found the method `Array#difference` to be so useful I proposed it be added to the Ruby Core ([here](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11815)). The response has been, er, underwhelming.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
def scramble(s1,s2)
  s2.chars.uniq.all? { |c| s1.count(c) >= s2.count(c) }
end
```

Another way:

```
def scramble(s1,s2)
  pool = s1.chars.group_by(&:itself)
  s2.chars.all? { |c| pool[c]&.pop }
end
```

Yet another:

```
def scramble(s1,s2)
  ('a'..'z').all? { |c| s1.count(c) >= s2.count(c) }
end
```

Since this appears to be [from codewars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/scramblies), I submitted my first two there. Both got accepted and the first one was a bit faster. Then I was shown solutions of others and saw someone using `('a'..'z')` and it's fast, so I include that here.

The codewars "performance tests" aren't shown explicitly but they're all up to about 45000 letters long. So I benchmarked these solutions as well as Cary's (yours was too slow to be included) on shuffles of the alphabet repeated to be about that long (and doing it 100 times):

```
               user     system      total        real
Stefan 1   0.812000   0.000000   0.812000 (  0.811765)
Stefan 2   2.141000   0.000000   2.141000 (  2.127585)
Other      0.125000   0.000000   0.125000 (  0.122248)
Cary 1     2.562000   0.000000   2.562000 (  2.575366)
Cary 2     3.094000   0.000000   3.094000 (  3.106834)
```

Moral of the story? `String#count` is fast here. Like, ridiculously fast. Almost *unbelievably* fast (I actually had to run extra tests to believe it). It counts through about *1.9 billion letters per second* (100 times 26 letters times 2 strings of ~45000 letters, all in 0.12 seconds). Note that the difference to my own first solution is just that I do `s2.chars.uniq`, and that increases the time from 0.12 seconds to 0.81 seconds. Meaning this double pass through one string takes about six times as long as the 52 passes for counting. The counting is about 150 times faster. I did expect it to be very fast, because it presumably just searches a byte in an array of bytes using C code (edit: [looks like it does](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/00716bee784e4f405707a38e8709e71490c7d1bb/string.c#L7532-L7534)), but this speed still surprised me.

Code:

```
require 'benchmark'

def scramble_stefan1(s1,s2)
  s2.chars.uniq.all? { |c| s1.count(c) >= s2.count(c) }
end

def scramble_stefan2(s1,s2)
  pool = s1.chars.group_by(&:itself)
  s2.chars.all? { |c| pool[c]&.pop }
end

def scramble_other(s1,s2)
  ('a'..'z').all? { |c| s1.count(c) >= s2.count(c) }
end

def scramble_cary1(str1, str2)
  h1 = char_counts(str1)
  h2 = char_counts(str2)
  h2.all? { |ch, nbr| nbr <= h1[ch] }
end
def char_counts(str)
  str.each_char.with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |ch, h| h[ch] += 1 }
end

def scramble_cary2(str1, str2)
  str2.chars.difference(str1.chars).empty?
end
class Array
  def difference(other)
    h = other.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |e,h| h[e] += 1 }
    reject { |e| h[e] > 0 && h[e] -= 1 }
  end
end

Benchmark.bmbm do |x|
  n = 100
  s1 = (('a'..'z').to_a * (45000 / 26)).shuffle.join
  s2 = s1.chars.shuffle.join
  x.report('Stefan 1') { n.times { scramble_stefan1(s1, s2) } }
  x.report('Stefan 2') { n.times { scramble_stefan2(s1, s2) } }
  x.report('Other') { n.times { scramble_other(s1, s2) } }
  x.report('Cary 1') { n.times { scramble_cary1(s1, s2) } }
  x.report('Cary 2') { n.times { scramble_cary2(s1, s2) } }
end
```